# Declaring TypeScript member in prototype rather than adding to 'this'

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following TypeScript:

```
class A {
    member = "value";
}
```

...is compiled to:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.member = "value";
    }
    return A;
})();
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }

    A.prototype.member = "value";

    return A;
})();
```

The reason for this is that I believe that the latter construct could be more efficient because (1) the assignment `this.member = "value"` statement would not have to be executed every time a new instance is created, and (2) instance memory payload would be smaller.

Disclaimer: I haven't bench marked the two constructs so I really don't know whether that is the case.

So my question is: **Is it possible to declare a "prototype member" using type script?**.

I'd also be happy if someone could explain **why type script is designed this way?**. (See [§8.4.1 in the specification](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf))

I understand that it would be stupid to declare mutable members in this way, but declarations of immutable primitives, like `string` and `number`, should be fine to set on the prototype, right?

A possible work around could be:

```
class A {
    member: string;
}

A.prototype.member = "value";
```

However, that won't work for private members:

```
class A {
    private member: string;
}

A.prototype.member = "value"; // error TS2107: 'A.member' is inaccessible.
```

Comment: Behind the scenes, isn't it essentially doing `this.member = A.prototype.member` in the constructor anyways? I don't think there's a performance benefit to doing this, but maybe there's someone who knows for sure. For me, I'd rather not sacrifice code quality for an extremely small performance gain.

Comment: No it is not. If you would re-assign `member` on `prototype` then that change would be visible on all instances that doesn't have an explicitly assigned member value.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. I'd never tried putting value types on prototype before, but that makes sense. By the way, there is a [performance benefit during initialization](http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-this-access/3) and the more properties you add the slower assigning to `this` gets.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the performance comparison!

Comment: By the way, it's only faster during initialization if you have a small amount of lookups. For example, to offset initializing 6 strings I had to do [~30 lookups](http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-this-access/5) (on my computer they're tied). So it seems that after accessing a variable ~5 times it isn't worth it to do this method. Maybe? So it just seems to depend on the situation whether this is worth it. I would still recommend not bothering because these micro-optimizations will just lead to your code being harder to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with a possible work around that works for private members too:

```
class A {
    private member: string;

    static __init = (() => {
        A.prototype.member = "value";
    })();
}
```

This is pretty nice; all code is within the class construct and I've avoided casting to `any` so it is still possible to track references to those private members (for refactoring, etc.).

A dummy `__init` member is declared on the class function when using this approach. Not a big issue though.

Comment: Nice solution! That's actually not so bad.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to declare a "prototype member" using type script?

No the language doesn't allow this at the moment.

**Workaround**

When the compiler is unhappy ... assert:

```
class A {
    private member: string;
}

(<any>A.prototype).member = "value"; // suppressed
```

> why type script is designed this way

Simply because it is non-idiomatic to have *non functions* on `prototype`.

> (1) the assignment this.member = "value" statement would not have to be executed every time a new instance is created, and (2) instance memory payload would be smaller.

However lookup *will definitely* be slower. Here is a sample test : http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-this-access

Comment: Casting to `any` is not a good way to go in my opinion. We would then loose track of where that member is used (refactoring, etc.) - which is one of the primary reasons why we use type script in the first place.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit on *"it is non-ideomatic to have non functions on prototype"*? I don't understand what non-idiomatic means :-)

Comment: i.e. you will not find much JavaScript code in the wild that puts members on `prototype`. I certainly don't recall seeing *any* code written that way

Comment: Really? I see several use cases for that: (1) default values for a settings object as an alternative to $.extend () and the likes. (2) efficiency of "classes" with MANY instances.

Comment: Here's one place in the type script source code where non-function members are assigned to the prototype: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/core.ts#L660

Comment: Nice benchmark in your edit! I created a modified version of it that shows that the `prototype`-variant is actually faster if you create a lot of instances. (one new instance and one member access per iteration): http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-this-access/4

Comment: Yes *creation* will be faster but *lookup* will be slower, this is exactly the tradeoff.

Comment: Yeah. And in my scenario I'll be creating a lot of instances and most of the time some of their properties will be left unread and untouched (except by the constructor). Therefore I would clearly benefit from using the `prototype` approach. Right?